# If $g$ is commutator then so is $g^m$ for $(m,o(g))=1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

There are certain theorems in finite group theory whose proofs involve character theory and for which there are still no character-free proofs. Among such is Frobenius theorem on transitive permutation groups. (Another *was* Burnside's $pq$ theorem; but there is now group theoretic proof.

I am considering one such theorem, whose proof is based on following theorem.

> **Theorem 1.** An element $g\in G$ is a commutator if and only if $\sum_{\chi\in{\rm Irr}(G)} \frac{\chi(g)}{\chi(1)}\neq 0.$

So if $m$ is an integer relatively prime to $o(g)=n$, then consider the Galois automorphism $\sigma$, which, on $n$-th roots of unity acts by $\zeta_n\mapsto \zeta_n^m$. Then $(\chi(g))^{\sigma}=\chi(g^m)$. Thus, if $g$ is a commutator, then applying $\sigma$ to inequality in theorem we get that $g^m$ is also a commutator. Thus,

> **Theorem 2.** If $g\in G$ is a commutator then so is $g^m$ for $(m,o(g))=1$.

The Theorem 2 is purely group theoretic; but proof involves character theory arguments. Question is now simple:

**Q.** Is there character-free proof for Theorem 2?

(I do not know whether this question has been considered before by anyone.)

Comment: With HNN extension (which needs no character theory) you can find a group $X$ containing $G$ such that $g$ and $g^m$ are conjugate in $X$. So then at least in $X$, the element $g^m$ is a commutator. Just an idea, I don't know if this could be used to show that $g^m$ is a commutator in $G$.

Comment: Also, the inverse of a commutator $[x,y]$ is equal to $[y,x]$, so the claim is clear if $m = o(g) - 1$. Now the smallest $o(g)$ where we need more than this is $o(g) = 5$: We should show that if $[x,y]^5 = 1$, then $[x,y]^2$ is a commutator. Not sure how to do even this case.

Comment: In the few examples I have considered (abelian, symmetric, alternating, dihedral groups), for each $g\in G$ and $m$ coprime to $g$, there is an automorphism of $G$ taking $g$ to $g^m$ (whether or not $g$ is a commutator). Is it possible this is always the case?

Comment: @JulianRosen: Definitely not. Now $g$ is conjugate in $G$ to $g^m$ for all $m$ coprime to $o(g)$ if and only if $g$ takes rational value on all irreducible characters. So it would be enough to find $G$ without outer automorphisms such that the character table contains irrational entries.  Probably there are much easier examples, but looking at some tables from books it seems the Mathieu group $M_{11}$ is one example like this.

Answer (score 4):

A character-free proof of this result of K. Honda (1953) has recently been found by Hendrik Lenstra. It has been published in *Operations Research Letters*, Powers of Commutators, Volume 51, Issue 1, January 2023, Pages 17-20. Here is the [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637722001481?via%3Dihub). The proof involves calculations in (several) group rings. It is fun and a joy to read!