# Powers of a commutator are commutators?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $g$ be a commutator.

It can be shown that if $m$ is a positive integer coprime to order of $g$, then $g^m$ is also a commutator ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259946/if-g-is-commutator-then-so-is-gm-for-m-og-1l)).

**Q.** Is there any example of a finite group such that $g$ is a commutator but for $m$ a divisor of order of $g$, the element $g^m$ is *not* a commutator?

Comment: Yes, $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(96,3)$.

Comment: @Derek: I assume that is the smallest example? Maybe it is possible to provide the actual presentation of the group, the element $g$ and divisor $m$.

Comment: I believe that two groups of order $96$ are the smallest groups in which not every element of the commutator subgroup is a commutator. I think only one of these is a counterexample to the question but I would need to check that. And $m=2$.

Comment: It is $((C4:C2):C4):C3$; one source for presentation is a paper "Commutators: A Survey" by Kappe and Morse. They give the presentation, you can easily find in it. Here $G'$ is Sylow $2$-subgroup (order $32$), but the number of commutators is $29$; they have order $2$ or $4$ (or $1$); among these $29$ members, one of order $4$ is desired $g$.

Comment: Paper of Kappe and Morse is here: bit.ly/2xiGWnT